# I am trying to make something like Facebook comment functionality. Read description what I am missing

Tags: jquery

My comments are posting through AJAX just fine but when I click on Like, the count does not update. But if I refresh the page once, and then click on like, the like count updates through AJAX. What I am missing?

Why The AJAX call on clicking like is not occurring when I post a new comment. Please help.

Here is my code.

**JQUERY :**

this part of code adds comment through ajax, submission via pressing ENTER

```
  $('textarea').keyup(function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
                    var content = this.value;
                    var caret = getCaret(this);
                    this.value = content.substring(0,caret)+
                                  "\n"+content.substring(caret,content.length);
                    event.stopPropagation();

               } else if(event.keyCode == 13) {

                    $.ajax({             
                                   type: "post",
                                   url: 'index2.php',
                                   data: $("#comment-form").serialize(),
                                   success: function(data)
                                   {
                                        $("#results").html(data);
                                   }
                                 });
                                 $("#comment").val('');
                         e.preventDefault();
               }
              });
```

this part of code explains the like count updating

```
              $("span[id^='comlike'] a").click(function() {
                //  alert('aaa');
                var idtest;
                idtest = $(this).attr('id');
                var myString = idtest;
                var parts = myString.split("like");
                var thePart = parts[1];

                   $.ajax({             
                                   type: "post",
                                   url: 'like.php',
                                   data: 'likeid='+thePart, // serializes the form's elements.
                                   success: function(data)
                                   {

                                     $("#likecount"+thePart).html(data);


                                   }
                                 });


              });
```

**HTML:**

this part of code is my HTML My comments are posting through AJAX

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {

  echo  '<div id="divcommentid_'.$row['id'].'">'.
          $row['comment'] . 
          '<br>'
          . '<div>'
             . '<span style="color:#999">Posted : '.$row['time'].'</span>&nbsp;'
             . '<span id="comlike'.$row['id'].'">'
                . '<a href="#" id="like'.$row['id'].'">Like</a>'
                . '&nbsp;'.''
                . '<span style="color:blue" id="likecount'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['like_count'].'</span>'
            . '</span>'
          . '</div></div>';

}?></div><br>
            <form role="form" id="comment-form" method="post" action="">


                <textarea class="form-control resizable comment-box required" rows="1" placeholder="Write your comment" id="comment" name="comment" size="80" ></textarea>

                <br>
              <!--        <input type=text class="form-control comment-box" rows="1" placeholder="Write your comment" id="comment" name="comment">    -->

                <input type="hidden" name="time" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
            </form>
```

this commentid div is on index2.php also, which is responded back to update the html of div id "results"

My comments are posting through AJAX just fine but when I click on Like, the count does not update. But if I refresh the page once, and then click on like, the like count updates through AJAX. What I am missing?

Why The AJAX call on clicking like is not occurring when I post a new comment.

Comment: Check out Facebook's dev section: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Comment: I want to make my own plugin sir.